# Nuxt nested routes

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js, nested-routes

Im having a basic universal app created with Nuxt.

Im new with vue and nuxt and im trying to understand how routing works, to be more specific how nested routes works.

So my projects structure is

```
├── parent
│   ├── child1.vue
│   └── child2.vue
├── parent.vue
```

and in the parent page i have two links for child1 and child2

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Parent page</h3>
        <nuxt-link to="/parent/child1"> about1 page</nuxt-link>
        <nuxt-link to="/parent/child2"> about2 page</nuxt-link>
    </div>
</template>
```

My goal is when i click on the links to go to next page for example `/parent/child2`,

but that doesn't happens. When i click on the links it reopens the same parent page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move file `parent.vue` to `parent/index.vue`

Comment: The solution you provided worked perfect. Even the parent.vue kept  his original path.

Answer (score 1):

just a small hint you can also use `parent/_slug.vue` for your children